# Why is a DNS server needed when setting up a static ip

Tags: networking, dns, routes, modem

So I am setting up my at home server, and I am setting up my static ip address. I noticed that I need to input my ISP's DNS servers. Why? It does not seem to list a DNS server for DHCP. If I truly have a static ip address (which RCN, my ISP, claims that I have), then why do I need a DNS? What is being resolved at the DNS? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: PS, I do know that DNS servers are used to resolve url's to ip addresses. I just do not see how this is relevant here

Answer (score 1):

As you said you need DNS server/s to resolve hostnames to IP addresses. If you do not use a DNS server your PC/router wouldn't know what's the IP of the sites you want to visit (unless you hardcode all the addresses, of course). This are resolving/recursive DNS servers, not authoritative DNS servers.

When you do not use DHCP these servers are not automatically obtained, that is why you need to manually put them.